# why add the class next left when I should add the active class in the boostrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

What I want to do is that when my question has a timer and the user next, that question disappears and I can not answer it.

Code:

```
var timer = $(".active").attr('data-timer');
if (timer == undefined) {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item').first();
    NextElement.addClass('active');
    $('.timer').remove();
} else {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var ActiveElement = $carousel.find('.item.active');
    ActiveElement.remove();
    var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item');
    NextElement.addClass('active');
    $('.timer').remove();
}
```

It does everything, except that when it enters the else instead of adding the active in my carousel it adds the class next left.

[image]

Instead of this class being added, it should be active, so when it re-enters the if the slide does not work anymore. Even add the following:

```
var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item').first();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `.first`

Just use `var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item')`, next only returns one element https://api.jquery.com/next/